# Add or Remove Dynamic Dependent Select Box data from two mysql tables using jQuery with PHP Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, dynamic

I need complete sample code to Add or Remove Dynamic Dependent Select Box data from two mysql tables using jQuery with PHP Ajax

Dependent select data should be come these below tables. And should be add and remove button to add row.
Category
Sub Category

Below is sample data, but in this, dependent  select data coming from only one mysql table.

https://www.webslesson.info/2019/09/add-or-remove-dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-with-php-ajax.html

Can any provide me sample demo with source code ?

[Please this sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTh5t.jpg)

Please see this image, There are three tables, (1) Items, (2) Category, (3) Sub Category, I need same like this, but data should come from Category table and sub category table in dependent select boxes. And this is multi dynamic row. Can you give me all demo code, becuase I do not know about Jave,Ajax and jQuery.

Below is sample demo and source code weblink, But in this sample, He is getting data from only one table for both dependent boxes category and sub category. Data should be come from two tables both dependent boxes.

[enter link description here](https://www.webslesson.info/2019/09/add-or-remove-dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-with-php-ajax.html)

I hope you understand what I required.

Comment: https://www.webslesson.info/2019/09/add-or-remove-dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-with-php-ajax.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.